# Enable AirPrint on HP LaserJet M1212nf MFP

Tags: usb, printer, printing, ios, imac

I am attempting to be able to AirPrint from my iOS devices (iPad 3rd gen, iPod touch 4th, iPhone 5, etc) to my existing LaserJet. I have read that this is possible with this printer.

My configuration is as follows:

- The printer is an **HP LasertJet M1212nf MFP**
- This printer is connected to my **iMac running Mountain Lion** through **USB**
- The iMac is connected to my home wireless network over WiFi
- The **iOS devices** are all running **latest iOS** versions

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the printer on the network, as opposed to shared from your iMac.  Plug the printer into your wireless router via the RJ45 (network cable) port.

If everything works as expected, your iOS devices will just see it when they are on the same wireless network.

If not, you'll need to go through the menus and configure the printer.

Any other devices using the printer currently (e.g. the iMac) will need to be configured to use the printer via the network, as opposed to the share you have off the iMac.